# Restarting Kubernetes job

Tags: kubernetes, jobs

I'm working with Kubernetes 1.26 on the server side (EKS) and kubectl client 1.27.1.

I have a job define in this way:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: build
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      volumes:
          .....
      containers:
          - name: build-tool
          ....
```

My pod dies for OOMKilled or some other reason, then Kubernetes launches another pod.
Why?

It is supposed not to be restarted.

Related reading:

- https://www.aquasec.com/cloud-native-academy/kubernetes-101/kubernetes-jobs/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed this section of the documentation:

> An entire Pod can also fail, for a number of reasons, such as when the pod is kicked off the node (node is upgraded, rebooted, deleted, etc.), or if a container of the Pod fails and the .spec.template.spec.restartPolicy = "Never". **When a Pod fails, then the Job controller starts a new Pod.** This means that your application needs to handle the case when it is restarted in a new pod. In particular, it needs to handle temporary files, locks, incomplete output and the like caused by previous runs.

The value of `spec.template.spec.restartPolicy` effects the response to failed *containers* in your Pod ([docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy)), but is not relevant to failures of the pod itself.

You can control how the Job controller responds to a failed *Pod* by setting a [podFailurePolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#pod-failure-policy).

Answer (score 0):

If restarting is not desired, the simplest solution is to use a plain pod instead of a job.